# Sci-fi book or series with three children working on a moon looking for ancient life? Has psychic ability 'mindspread'

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, psychic, moon

Looking for the name of a book or series from the 90s (?) where I think three children (one boy, from Earth, and two children from other planets) worked on or were taken to a moon of Jupiter (?) to investigate long-dead alien life.
There was prejudice against people not from Earth, and one of the non-Earth children had a name or surname like 'Tenoto' or 'Tennoto'.

> Actually meaning 1002 or 10-02, based on the number on a barcode meant to only show up once she matured.

A condition officially called mindspread caused static on nearby electronic devices. People with the condition were perjoratively called scatterbrained.

> The protagonist's mindspread got worse/more powerful after accidentally swallowing a shard of ice on the planet.